# Pop-up window scrolls back to the top when closed

Tags: jquery, html, popup, window

```
/*CSS */  
#popup { background-color: #fff; border: 1px #000 solid; display: block; position: fixed; padding: 20px; top: 200px; left: 50%; margin-left: -300px; width: 600px; z-index: 1; }

/* JQuery */
$('#show-popup').live('click', function() 
    {
        var tempWindow = $('<div id="popup">This is a draggable pop-up window created with JQuery and JQuery UI <a href="#" id="popup-close">Close</a></div>').draggable();
        $('body').append(tempWindow);
    });

$('#popup-close').live('click', function()
{
    $(this).parent().remove();
});

/* HTML */
<a href="#" id="show-popup">Open popup window</a>
```

The pop-up works, it opens normally, you can drag it around the page and it sticks to its position, but when you close it, it scrolls back to the top of the page. How can I prevent this?

Comment: -1 There are hardly any details here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out; Forgot to return false when the close link was clicked so it redirected to page.php#.

Answer (score 0):

On the close event, save the coordinates of the the window in a variable.

```
var coords = $('#popup').position();
```

Then when you open it back up set it to the same location.

```
$('<div id="popup">...</div>').css({position: 'absolute', top: coords.top, left: coords.left});
```

There is some logic missing here since you don't have a ton of details, but this should do the trick.

Comment: My bad, forgot to add the code for closing the popup... Anyway, the problem is that when I open the popup, scroll down a bit and close it (now with all the necessary code in the first post) it scrolls back to the top of the page automatically. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
```